# Is there a book on the phenomena of Equilibrium?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, book-recommendation, mathematical-modeling, statics

Equilibrium phenomena are ubiquitous.
Is there a book that especially studies/explains the phenomena of Equilibrium?

Comment: Use keyword : "statics" (as opposed to "dynamics") in your queries.

Comment: @JeanMarie I just did. Thank You. Do you have any book or suggestions in mind?

Comment: This is possibly the most non-specific question I've seen asked on this site. Arguably, the entirety of elliptic PDE, most non-elliptic PDE theory, almost all of dynamical systems, and large parts of other areas of mathematics (e.g. algebraic and differential geometry) study equilibrium. If you want a real answer, you need to be way more specific about what you are looking for and why.

Comment: @user378654 that was intentional because I want a book on the general treatment of Equilibrium from different mathematical viewpoints